# Detect multiple keypress in Backbone

Tags: backbone.js

I am trying to catch e keypress event like **Alt + g**, my backbone code is something like this right now:

```
class MyView extends Backbone.View
  template: ...

  events:
    "keydown input" : "logKey"

  logKey: (e) ->
    if e.keyCode == 18 and e.keyCode == 71
      console.log('did it!')
```

Which doesnt work, as there is only one event keycode at a time.

How could this be achieved? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not look for `keypress` instead of `keydown`? Something like this:

```
class MyView extends Backbone.View
  events:
    "keypress input" : "logKey"

  logKey: (e) ->
    console.log('did it') if(e.keyCode == 169)
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/fmr8D/

Comment: I don't mind if it is keypress, BTW what would mean keycode 169? Alt + g? Dont't know how to trigger the event in the JSfiddle. Thanks for posting :)

Comment: Yeah, you'd be looking for `if(e.keyCode == 169)` with key press. Just click on the `<input>` and hit Alt+g

Answer (score -1):

You'll have to set a separate variable to keep track of modifier keys and check for that on your keydown events. Like:

```
events:
    "keydown input" : "logKeyDown",
    "keyup input" : "logKeyUp"

logKey: (e) ->
    if e.keyCode == 18
         altDown = true

    if altDown && e.keyCode == 71
      console.log('did it!')

logKeyUp: (e) ->
    if e.keyCode == 18
        altDown = false
```

Comment: Don't you mean `@altDown = true`?

Comment: This was mi idea as well, thought there was a better -elegant- way to do it. Thanks, I will test if it works for me